# stoichiometric crystal

Tags: stoichiometry, crystal-structure

I wonder if there is something like a "stoichiometric crystal"? In other words: Is it possible to have a crystal that is non-stoichiometric?

I'm not interested in crystal defects but don't want to ignore them.

Comment: Well, $\ce{Fe_{0.95}O}$ is definitely a thing, and crystalline at that. As for the defects, unless you are using some unconventional definition of a crystal, they are inevitable.

Comment: Thanks, I guess, what I actually wanted to know is: Are there crystals which are not stoichiometric?

Comment: Crystals of alums  $\ce{KAl(SO4)2.12 H2O}$  and  $\ce{KCr(SO4)2.12 H2O}$   have ions $\ce{Cr^3+}$ and $\ce{Al^3+}$ freely interchangeable in any ratio, making possible the non stoichiometric $\ce{K(Al,Cr)(SO4)2.12 H2O}$, if crystalized in mixed solutions - once done at home as a young student.

Comment: There are many binary phases that have broad phase fields. One example is titanium nitride. But, being off-stoichiometry means that there are vacancies on the nitrogen sub-lattice.

Comment: Can it be said, that a pure/ideal crystal has to be stochiometric? In case it consists of several different elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending the first part of your question, i.e. are there *stoichiometric crystals* as in *crystals of stoichiometric composition*, the answer is **yes**.  These are **co-crystals** IUCr defines as

> «Solid consisting of a crystalline single-phase material composed of two or more different molecular and/or ionic compounds generally in a stoichiometric ratio which are neither solvates nor simple salts.»
>
> source: [IUCr Online Dictionary of Crystallography](https://dictionary.iucr.org/Co-crystal)

While this excludes crystals of e.g., $\ce{CuSO4 * 5 H2O}$, there are plenty examples consisting of organic molecules such as the 1:1 mixture of quinole and pyridine ([reference](https://doi.org/10.1107/S1600536804024547)), or the 2:1 co-crystal of meloxicam and acetyl­endi­carb­­oxy­lic acid ([reference](https://doi.org/10.1107/S2056989016018909)) to mention just two.

Since the simultaneous presence of two components in one crystal typically alters the physical properties, e.g., of the rate of dissolution (which may translate into a change of rate their constituents become accessible for an organism [[ADMET data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADME-Tox)]), this is a large field of research of interest for pharmaceuticals and material science.   See, for example, the reviews by Buddhadev, Nugrahani, or Ross. Again, it is a large field of research; don't drown in the literature.

**References:**

Buddhadev, S. S.; Garala, K. C. Pharmaceutical Cocrystals—A Review. *Proceedings* **2020**, *62*, 14; [doi 10.3390/proceedings2020062014](https://doi.org/10.3390/proceedings2020062014), open access.

Nugrahani, I.; Jessica, M. A. Amino Acids as the Potential Co-Former for Co-Crystal Development: A Review. *Molecules* **2021**, *26*, 3279; [doi 10.3390/molecules26113279](https://doi.org/10.3390/molecules26113279) , open access.

Ross, S. A.; Lamprou D. A., Douroumis D. Engineering and manufacturing of pharmaceutical co-crystals: a review of solvent-free manufacturing technologies. *Chem. Commun.* **2016**, *52*, 8772-8786; [doi 10.1039/C6CC01289B](https://doi.org/10.1039/C6CC01289B).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! A crystal is not necessarily stoichiometric, or? I mean a pure crystal would not fall within such a description(?).

Comment: It is not clear if "stoichimetric" in your question about a "stoichiometric crystal" refers to a) compounds (like above quinole:pyridine), or b) like in Ivan's example $\ce{Fe_{0.95}O}$.  Chemistry "to the letter of the book in high school" expects/only allows either $\ce{FeO}$ (only Fe(II)), or $\ce{Fe2O3}$ (only Fe(III)), or $\ce{Fe3O4}$ (with Fe(II) and (Fe(III)) to keep the subject accessible enough without entering into study of chemistry at an university.

Comment: @Buttonwood I intuitively understand the OP meaning "stoichiometric crystals" as crystals where constituent molar ratios are ratios of small integers, similarly as ratios in chemical equations. the question may be, what deviation is just a corruption and what would be "nonstoichiometric crystal".

Comment: @Poutnik Yes, what Poutnik said :) At least this is how I'd understand it but I'm not a chemist(?).

Comment: Then «non-stoichimetric» crystals were (iron oxides/sulfides appear to more prone to this, than other metal oxides/sulfides) e.g., with Frenkel .or./.and. Schottky defects (an atom in excess [definitely too many]/an atom missing [a vacancy] where anticipated on the lattice).  Right of the tip of my hat, I don't know of an (equivalent) example for a purely organic crystal («organic» as antonym to «inorganic»).